# neo4j spark connector: mvn clean install assembly:single error

Tags: maven, apache-spark, neo4j, connector

I am working on neo4j-spark connector. After cloning and moving to the directory, I did `mvn clean install assembly:single`. It throws error :

```
Tests in error: 
  runMatrixQueryDFSchema(org.neo4j.spark.Neo4jDataFrameTest): Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12, localhost): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 1

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 42.538s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 24 19:18:07 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 72M/1016M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project neo4j-spark-connector: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /data/neo4j-spark-connector/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

How do I get rid of it? Do I need to do anything else to build target/neo4j-spark-connector_2.11-full-2.0.0-M1.jar for Scala 2.11. I have installed Spark 2.0.0 installed. I have it saved in the directory same as that for neo4j-spark-connector. Do I need to save it somewhere else? How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved now. You can take latest pull from the [neo4j-spark-connector repository](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector) and get it to work.

Thanks.